What aria attributes to be used in a dropdown that has filters button (which is a custom Lit component) and how to handle its accessibility?
The dropdown has a search input and filter such as All, Volume, Trend, Momentum, these filters   are    created in a custom component. On select of dropdown the focus is on search box and on click of arrow down I traverse the list items. And on click of tab we move across filters buttons, and on click of enter/space the list items are filtered. But when the focus is on filters and  I arrow down to traverse through the list of items , those items are not displayed on screen reader.
May i know how can i resolve this issue of accessibility?
Dropdown image
 Have tried using aria-activedescendant and aria-owns but none worked, just to note that my       filters  are in custom component and i render it in my main dropdown component.

How to make sure that i get the list items displayed on the screen when the focus is on filter??
 serach box code in dropdown component :
 <div class="indicator-search" @keydown=${this.trackKeyboard}>
 <input
 id="indicator-input"
 type="text"
 autocomplete="off"
 aria-label="search indicators"
 aria-controls="indicators-list"
 aria-activedescendant=${activeDescendant}
@input=${this.searchIndicators}>
</div>


Button-group used in dropdown component:
<div
@keydown=${this.trackKeyboard}
@keyup=${this.onKeyUp}>
<button-group
.options=${this.indicatorTypeList}
 @change-input=${this.toggleIndicatorTypes}>
</button-group>
</div>`

Dropdown component list items code:
<ul 
@keydown=${this.trackKeyboard}
@keyup=${this.onKeyUp}
id="indicators-list" 
class="list-reset" 
role="listbox"
tabindex="0"
aria-multiselectable="true" 
aria-label="indicators"
aria-activedescendant=${activeDescendant}>
 this.indicatorOptions.map((item, index) => {
            return html`
                      <li
                        id="${item.id}-option"
                        class="indicator-option ${classMap({ focus: index === focusIndex })}"
                        role="option"
                        aria-selected=${index === focusIndex}
                        @click=${() => this.onOptionClick(item)}>
                        ${item.displayName}
                      </li>`;
          })      
 </ul>


How about the aria-controls property/attribute together with an id and aria-labelledby property/attribute?
